# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault (ion)

Tags: java, android, ssl

I'm working with this library: https://github.com/koush/ion/ to get external json and image, and when I run my app (Android 2.2, API 8) or (Android 4.0.3 API 15)...

**LOGCAT:**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault
            at com.koushikdutta.ion.conscrypt.ConscryptMiddleware.initialize(ConscryptMiddleware.java:50)
            at com.koushikdutta.ion.conscrypt.ConscryptMiddleware.initialize(ConscryptMiddleware.java:82)
            at com.koushikdutta.ion.conscrypt.ConscryptMiddleware.getSocket(ConscryptMiddleware.java:117)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpClient.executeAffinity(AsyncHttpClient.java:303)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpClient.access$100(AsyncHttpClient.java:50)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpClient$1.run(AsyncHttpClient.java:189)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.lockAndRunQueue(AsyncServer.java:708)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.runLoop(AsyncServer.java:725)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.run(AsyncServer.java:626)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.access$700(AsyncServer.java:41)
            at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$13.run(AsyncServer.java:568)
```

**My Gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('my-proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
}
```

Does anyone know why is this happening? ):

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/koush/ion/issues/538) about this apparently

Comment: Thank You @Tunaki, I found the solution [here](https://github.com/koush/ion/issues/559#issuecomment-117362368).